# Spring Batch: What happens if a ExecutionContextPromotionListener can't save a job parameter?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I'm trying to understand `StepExecutionListener`. In my tests, exceptions thrown in a listener (for example, in `afterStep` or `ExecutionContextPromotionListener`) are ignored by Spring Batch. I can see the exception in the logfile, but the job keeps working and finish with ExitStatus *COMPLETED*.

Now I'm just wondering what happens if an `ExecutionContextPromotionListener` can't save a step execution parameter as a job parameter in the spring batch database if this is not available at that exact moment?

If the job just continues, I can never get the job parameter in the next step. This is a very unpleasant and unexpected behavior - especially because this procedure is recommended as best practice here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/patterns.html#passingDataToFutureSteps

Have I misunderstood something or is the `ExecutionContextPromotionListener` not working properly in this error scenario?